# Accessing the OLD/NEW table value in a trigger function in plain SQL

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to build a trigger function to automatically update parent order values any time any of it's items changes.

This is what I have created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_totals() RETURNS void AS $$
    UPDATE orders SET
       total_fees = (SELECT SUM(fees) FROM order_items WHERE order_id = OLD.order_id),
       total_profit = (CASE WHEN total_cost IS NOT NULL THEN total - total_tax - total_cost - (SELECT SUM(fees) FROM order_items WHERE order_id = OLD.order_id) ELSE NULL END)
    WHERE id = OLD.order_id;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE TRIGGER update_totals AFTER INSERT 
OR UPDATE OF fees
ON order_items INITIALLY DEFERRED
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.* ) EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_totals();
```

When I try to run this, I get this error:

```
missing FROM-clause for table "old"
```

I tried creating a reference to the original table in the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_totals AFTER INSERT 
OR UPDATE OF fees
ON order_items
REFERENCING OLD ROW AS old_order
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.* ) EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_totals();
```

But that just gives the error `syntax error at or near "REFERENCING"`.

How do I get the `order_id` from the original `order_items` table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Firstly**, to create a trigger on the `order_items` table, the `update_totals()` must be a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) which `RETURNS TRIGGER` (**bold** is mine).

> A data change trigger is declared as a function with no arguments and
>   a **return type of trigger**. Note that the function must be declared with
>   **no arguments** even if it expects to receive some arguments specified in
>   CREATE TRIGGER

If not, It causes an error `ERROR: function func_order_items must return type trigger`.

**Secondly**, please remember that you cannot have `OLD` when `AFTER INSERT` on the trigger. If not, It raises an error `ERROR:  record "old" is not assigned yet`.

**Finally**, please take a look at the example as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, X INT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_items (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ORDER_ID INT, Y INT); 

INSERT INTO orders VALUES(1, 0);
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES(10, 1, 20);
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES(11, 1, 30);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_order_items() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    UPDATE orders
    SET X = (SELECT SUM(Y) FROM order_items WHERE order_id = OLD.order_id)
    WHERE ID = OLD.order_id;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    UPDATE orders
    SET X = (SELECT SUM(Y) FROM order_items WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id)
    WHERE ID = NEW.order_id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_order_items 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON order_items 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_order_items();

UPDATE order_items SET Y = 200 WHERE ID = 10;
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES (12, 1, 200);
```

Comment: I would add a further point, namely you cannot use plain SQL as the language for a trigger function.

Comment: Accourding to the documentation:
The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null. However, any of these types of triggers might still abort the entire operation by raising an error...

so I think that RETURN NEW; should be updated to return null;